# Htaccess rewrite to hide long parameters in search

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a file named movies.php to search for movies ,
the are many movies so i had to make a pagination system , the url after searching is something like This :

```
            ?pn=2&title=&category=&year=2014
```

i need some help with htaccess to make the url : /1/title/category/year/ 
for example .. , and hide the php in movies.php ,the final url must look something like this 
movies/title/action(forexample)/2014 ..

Comment: Can you show your attempt in question?

Comment: i don't have any htaccess code for now

Comment: Sorry but this this is not `give me code` service. Try something and post your attempt here (even if it is not working).

Answer (score 0):

To do that you use URL Rewrite
 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html